# NPM is throwing ENOVERSION when trying to publish a package

Tags: npm

I've published a package to npm (`my-package@1.0.0`) but right after I decided to unpublish it later (I know now it was not a good decision). I have made all the changes I wanted in the package and tried to publish it again running npm publish `my-package@1.0.1` but now I'm getting the following error in terminal:

`npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS`
`npm ERR! No valid versions available for my-package`

I tried to run `npm clear cache`. Again, I think it wasn't a good decision.